# How to use azimuthTo and distanceTo of QGeoCoordinate

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to use azimuthTo and distanceTo of QGeoCoordinate. I set lat and long with contructor or using setLatitude and setLongitude, but the result of  azimuthTo or distanceTo  is always 0. This is my code:

```
QGeoCoordinate geo;
geo.setLatitude(90);
geo.setLongitude(90);
QGeoCoordinate geo2;
if (!geo.isValid())
cout<< "invalid coordinate"<<endl;

str = QString::number((float)geo2.azimuthTo(geo))";
```

My str is always 0. Have you got some information about it?

Comment: `QGeoCoordinate geo2;` creates an invalid coordinate. You must specify its latitude and longitude.

Comment: Yes, you're right, thank you!